# Getting wrong mutual friends count from facebook

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get mutual friends from facebook but it is giving me wrong result. The  total number of mutual friends count which I am getting is right but when the data is users is not coming

Request

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1744744292507346?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends{name,picture.type(large)})&access_token=access_token
```

Response

```
{
   "context": {
      "mutual_friends": {
         "data": [
            {
               "name": "Gaurav Varshney",
               "picture": {
                  "data": {
                     "is_silhouette": false,
                     "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/15541198_1872071033026134_3669335060573505093_n.jpg?oh=d4a95ee6cdb8d401be06e8f10fbf6d50&oe=59B0C911"
                  }
               },
               "id": "1919297771636793"
            }
         ],
         "paging": {
            "cursors": {
               "before": "MTkxOTI5Nzc3MTYzNjc5MwZDZD",
               "after": "MTkxOTI5Nzc3MTYzNjc5MwZDZD"
            }
         },
         "summary": {
            "total_count": 2
         }
      },
      "id": "dXNlcl9jb250ZAXh0OgGQHYKW1ALzRNZBAkUhMk2uDFtLZBBkzlasCZAq98zEqnPZBjqy7beHZBJZCVZB7STTw6yMnKC0w4qDA05ZBOGQ3RdRoPjfi1cbAmnChBQ1xLYpJuuKrIEZD"
   },
   "id": "1744744292507346"
}
```

I am only getting 1 friend since total_count is showing 2 .Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong?And how can I use paging ??

When try to hit all_mutual_friends

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1744744292507346?fields=context.fields(all_mutual_friends{name,picture.type(large)})&access_token=access_token

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#10) To use all_mutual_friends on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 10,
      "fbtrace_id": "HF3ZO8U3eLW"
   }
}
```

Comment: total_count is the overall number of friends the two users have in common; however you only get those friends returned in the data structure, that are also users of the same app.

Comment: If you want those mutual friends that are not users of your app as well, then you need to use `all_mutual_friends` instead.

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: `all_mutual_friends` imposes additional requirements on the API requests; did you take care of those …?

Comment: I am not able to assign this permission because when I am trying to give this all_mutual_friends permission  there is no option showing of this permissions

Comment: PLease see I have updated my answer. I have even user_friends permission from facebook

Comment: Is the user with id `1744744292507346` added to a role in your app?

Comment: what do u mean by role in my app.?In my application this user with facebook uid 1744744292507346 has logged in but still mutual friends count result show wrong

Comment: Role in the app = the user is an admin, developer or tester for the app. The last error message you quoted tells you that it will only work for such accounts, before you submit your app for review.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lack of documentation about this feature and I had to dig about it. Mainly regarding on how to request that with Graph API.

That's how I'm doing and it is working, with some flaws that I will explain later:

Let's say we have here UserA and UserB. You need to collect the context-id of each of the user and save it on the server side because it must be used later on.

So, UserA connects and want to request mutual friends with UserB which is already connected. What you will need to do is:

UserA FB Graph request using this:

`/'{{UserB context-id}}/all_mutual_friends?limit=5000', 'get'`

also sending UserA fbaccesstoken

I use the limit 5000 to avoid pagination on the data results.

Now, the flaws:

The all_mutual_friends is giving me some headaches. I may be completely wrong, of course, but I debugged it for days and it seems there are some issues with Facebook when the feature is still in development mode and not public/authorized by FB. Don't know, I need to ask for permission to see that in production.

On my application I realised there are sometimes some mutual_friends are not actually listed and it is not a fault of the script, but probably some users configuration that avoid using this or some facebook problem. IDN.

Anyways, that's the way you should request mutual friends.

Hope it helps.